# Extension of the exponential power series to an integral

Tags: power-series, exponential-function, improper-integrals, gamma-function

We know that the power series of the exponential gives us
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad \mathrm{e}^x = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

We also know that the Euler's Gamma function $\Gamma$ is an extension of the factorial to complex numbers.

Since the integral can sometimes be considered as a continuous sum, I was wondering if the below function $f$ is a center of interest in Mathematics. If so, does it have a name? does it have special properties?

Let $f$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f:x\longmapsto \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^t}{\Gamma(t+1)}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Comment: Hi, I found some discussion of this function [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351423/an-analogue-of-the-exponential-function-by-replacing-infinite-series-with-improp) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158527/the-function-fx-int-0-infty-fracxt-gammat1-dt). No special name is given to it though.